# How to lock the mouse pointer to one screen?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, multiple-monitors

How can I lock the mouse pointer to one screen in a dual/multiple screen setup?

Ideally, I would like to be able to move the pointer from one screen to another **only** while holding a key (like CTRL). I mention this because I used an application in another OS that had this feature and was really convenient.